# Group by function in sql

Tags: sql

It is throwing a error for the group by function. how do i fix it

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRANSBDATE,'MON-YYYY')PERIOD,B.CURCODE,COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMERID) UNIQUECUSTOMERS,COUNT(CURCODE)TRANS  
FROM FX_TRANSHEADER A,FX_TRANSDETAIL B
WHERE A.TRANSNO = B.TRANSNO AND A.TRANSBDATE BETWEEN '01-JAN-2018' AND '30-JUN-2019' AND C_IDTYPE NOT IN ('CR')
ORDER BY 1 , 4
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TRANSBDATE,'MON-YYYY')PERIOD,COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMERID),COUNT(CURCODE)
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: We love that you're here and you need to tell us more. What do your tables look like?

Comment: Use just `GROUP BY TRANSBDATE`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GROUP BY only needs the fields on which you want to aggregate:

```
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TRANSBDATE,'MON-YYYY')PERIOD, B.CURCODE
```

So not on `COUNT(B.CURCODE)` but on CURCODE

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRANSBDATE,'MON-YYYY')PERIOD,B.CURCODE,COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMERID) UNIQUECUSTOMERS,COUNT(CURCODE)TRANS  
FROM FX_TRANSHEADER A,FX_TRANSDETAIL B
WHERE A.TRANSNO = B.TRANSNO AND A.TRANSBDATE BETWEEN '01-JAN-2018' AND '30-JUN-2019' AND C_IDTYPE NOT IN ('CR')
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TRANSBDATE,'MON-YYYY'),B.CURCODE
ORDER BY 1 , 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include aggregation functions in the `GROUP BY`.  You only want the *unaggregated* columns from the `SELECT`.

I would recommend writing the query as:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(H.TRANSBDATE,'MON-YYYY') as PERIOD,
       D.CURCODE,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ?.CUSTOMERID) as UNIQUECUSTOMERS,
       COUNT(*) as TRANS  
FROM FX_TRANSHEADER H JOIN
     FX_TRANSDETAIL D
     ON H.TRANSNO = D.TRANSNO 
WHERE H.TRANSBDATE >= DATE '2018-01-01' AND
      H.TRANSBDATE < DATE '2018-07-01' AND
      ?.C_IDTYPE NOT IN ('CR')
ORDER BY 1 , 4
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(H.TRANSBDATE, 'MON-YYYY');
```

The `?` is for the column aliases for the tables that have the specified columns.

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- Use meaningful table aliases (table abbreviations) rather than arbitrary letters.
- Use `DATE` to represent date literals, so your code is not tied to particular internationalization settings on your server.
- Replaced `BETWEEN` with two direct comparisons.  This is particularly important in databases such as Oracle, where the `DATE` data type has a time component.